# Bootstrap.js: align input-group next to dropdown menu

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap.js and am trying to a align an input-group side-by-side with a dropdown but can't get it to work--code and figure below. I have tried the table approach but end up the elements vertically misaligned. What should I do?

```html
    <div class="dropup">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Color By
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="colorBy">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('diameter')">Diameter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('lof_seg')">LOF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('inst_year')">Year</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('material')">Material</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="width: 500px">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="resetView()">Reset View</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomToPipe()">Zoom to Pipe</button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="pipeId" name="pipeId" value="Pipe ID" class="form-control" style="width: max-content;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I get:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <div class="dropup">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Color By
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="colorBy">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('diameter')">Diameter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('lof_seg')">LOF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('inst_year')">Year</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor('material')">Material</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="resetView()">Reset View</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomToPipe()">Zoom to Pipe</button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="pipeId" name="pipeId" value="Pipe ID" class="form-control" style="width: max-content;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```